# Dependências NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Olá,
Uma coisa que me tem preocupado, é a quantidade de dependências em projetos nodejs que tenho visto.
O que acontece se eu tiver uma depedência em um projeto nodejs e o autor desta a eliminar? Como posso garantir que a dependêcia cada vez que digito `npm install` seja instalada mesmo que esta tenha sido removida pelo seu autor, há alguma forma de controlar este possiveis problemas?

Comment: Se o autor remover a dependência, pode acontecer isso: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/03/23/npm_left_pad_chaos/

Comment: @hkotsubo eu estava lembrando disso.

Answer (score 3):

## NPM Unpublish Policy

Este documento descreve suas opções ao tentar cancelar a publicação de um pacote publicado no registro público.

Os dados do registro são imutáveis, ou seja, uma vez publicado, um pacote não pode ser alterado. Fazemos isso por razões de segurança e estabilidade dos usuários que dependem desses pacotes. Portanto, se você já publicou um pacote chamado "bob" na versão 1.1.0, nenhum outro pacote poderá ser publicado com esse nome nessa versão. Isso é verdade mesmo se esse pacote não for publicado.

No entanto, devido a acidentes, permitimos que você cancele a publicação de pacotes nas situações descritas abaixo. Caso contrário, você sempre poderá descontinuar um pacote.

### Pacotes publicados há menos de 72 horas

Para pacotes recém-criados, desde que nenhum outro pacote no Registro Público npm dependa do seu pacote, você pode cancelar a publicação a qualquer momento nas primeiras 72 horas após a publicação.

Pacotes publicados há mais de 72 horas
Independentemente de há quanto tempo um pacote foi publicado, você pode cancelar a publicação de um pacote que:

- nenhum outro pacote no Registro público npm dependa dele
- teve menos de 300 downloads na última semana
- tem um único proprietário / mantenedor

### Como cancelar a publicação

Para despublicar uma úniva versão de um pacote npm execute o `npm unpublish <package_name>@<version>`.

Se todas as versões de um pacote puderem ser publicadas, você pode despublicar todas as versões de uma vez executando o comando `npm unpublish <package_name> --force`.

#### Considerações:

- Depois que o package@version for usado, você nunca poderá usá-lo novamente. Você deve publicar uma nova versão, mesmo que você não tenha publicado a antiga.
- Depois de cancelar a publicação de um pacote, você não poderá desfazer a publicação.
- Se você cancelar a publicação completa de todas as versões de um pacote, não poderá publicar nenhuma nova versão desse pacote até que passem 24 horas.

---

Obs.: Fiz uma tradução rápida do conteúdo deste [site](https://www.npmjs.com/policies/unpublish), á medida que eu tiver tempo melhoro o texto

Licença: [Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International (CC BY-SA 4.0)](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/#)

Answer (score 0):

O Arquivo `package.json` mantém todos os dados das dependências, como nome e versão, caso alguém apague algum módulo do `node_modules` como você mesmo disse, ela será instalada, porém se alguém deletar o nome do pacote no arquivo `package.json`, não conheço uma maneira de bloquear a edição do arquivo

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Cláudio! Tudo bem?

Então, toda vez que usamos o npm ou o yarn, é criado um arquivo chamado Package.json, lá é escrito todos os dados pertinentes a sua aplicação, como nome do autor, tipo da licença e principalmente todas as dependências npm que o projeto utiliza.

exemplo:

```
{
  "name": "servidor",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Livraria Casa do Codigo",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon src/app/server.js"
  },
  "author": "Vitor Cordeiro",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.16.3",
    "marko": "4.13.4-1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "exact": "^0.8.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.4"
  }
}
```

em "dependencies" estão todas as dependencias do seu projeto. E em "devDependencies" estão as dependencias de desenvolvimento, aquelas que são necessárias apenas no desenvolvimento e no modo produção são retiradas do projeto.

**E se eu apagar alguma dependência??**

Quando isso acontecer, uma dica: Relaxa! hahahahaha
Inclusive, quando equipes de desenvolvimento estão trabalhando juntas e precisam compartilhar o projeto com outras pessoas, eles enviam somente as pastas que contém código e lógica, e o arquivo Package.json.

O arquivo node_modules não é enviado junto, para diminuir o tamanho do arquivo enviado.

A pessoa que pegou os arquivos digita apenas 1 comando no terminal

> npm install

com esse comando, o npm irá "ler" o conteúdo do arquivo Package.json e verá todas as dependências que o projeto contém e irá instala-las automaticamente.

Espero que tenha respondido sua pergunta!

até a próxima!

Comment: Ele não perguntou sobre apagar a dependência dentro de node_modules, mas sim se o autor deletar ela do npm

Comment: [aqui](https://www.npmjs.com/policies/unpublish) tem os detalhes sobre isso